# Identifying Exception Type in a handler Catch Block

Tags: c#, exception

I have created custom exception class

```
public class Web2PDFException : Exception
{
    public Web2PDFException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { ... }
}
```

In my application how can I find out if it is my custom exception or not?

```
try {  ...  }

catch (Exception err)
{
//Find exception type here
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

UPDATED: assuming [C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6), the chances are that your case can be expressed as an exception filter. This is the ideal approach from a performance perspective assuming your requirement can be expressed in terms of it, e.g.:

```
try
{
}
catch ( Web2PDFException ex ) when ( ex.Code == 52 )
{
}
```

---

Assuming C# < 6, the most efficient is to catch a specific `Exception` type and do handling based on that. Any catch-all handling can be done separately

```
try
{
}
catch ( Web2PDFException ex )
{
}
```

or

```
try
{
}
catch ( Web2PDFException ex )
{
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
}
```

or (if you need to write a general handler - which is generally a bad idea, but if you're sure it's best for you, you're sure):

```
 if( err is Web2PDFException)
 {
 }
```

or (in certain cases if you need to do some more complex type hierarchy stuff that cant be expressed with `is`)

```
 if( err.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Web2PDFException)))
 {
 }
```

<strike>or switch to VB.NET or F# and use `is` or `Type.IsAssignableFrom` in Exception Filters</strike>

Comment: if( err is Web2PDFException) is that I needed :)

Comment: To use the "is" operator he does not need to switch to VB.NET

Comment: @BeowulfOF: I know, but if he's just trying to do filtering based on types - i.e. some sort of conditional catching etc., it may be useful to use an is *in an exception filter rather than a catch block* - it may be an avenue of approach which works. My initial suggestion (and it's still in the answer) is an is in the catch block. Bottom line here is that given that using an `is` is normally a bad smell, we might as well have a laundry list of possible solutions and let Tomas pick what suits him best in his specific context. But yes, it's unlikely.

Comment: @AnonymousDownvoter: Any good reason why? @BeowulfOF: Didnt mean to imply that `is` is only in VB, just that exception filters are not exposed in C#

Comment: @RubenBartelink could you explain why writing a general handler is generally a bad idea? I am thinking of applying this solution - how does this differ from a list of catch statements ending with catch(Exception ex){//do something}

Comment: @user3141326 I was just saying that in general code will be clearer and more efficient if you have a catch per type rather than having a generic one and then doing type checks (e.g. `Type.IsAssignableFrom`) inside that catch block esp if you then end-up rethrowing if stuff turns out not to be of interest [in which case either an exception filter or multiple specific catches would have been more efficient and clearer]. If your situation warrants a catch-all, then by all means do a `catch {` or `catch (Exception ex) {`.

Comment: +for catch catch

Answer (score 87):

When dealing with situations where I don't exactly know what type of exception might come out of a method, a little "trick" I like to do is to recover the Exception's class name and add it to the error log so there is more information.

```
try
{
   <code>

} catch ( Exception caughtEx )
{
   throw new Exception("Unknown Exception Thrown: "
                       + "\n  Type:    " + caughtEx.GetType().Name
                       + "\n  Message: " + caughtEx.Message);
}
```

I do vouch for always handling Exceptions types individually, but the extra bit of info can be helpful, specially when dealing with code from people who love to capture catch-all generic types.

Comment: I'm confused here (esp by the upvotes). You're replacing a useful exception with a stacktrace with another which only has the highlights? Even if you made the exception refer to `caughtEx` as a child, I'd wonder what the point is (if you show the full `exception.ToString()` it'll show you the type anyway). I could understand if you were logging it at this point prior to doing a `throw;`...

Comment: In my case I needed this for logging purposes, so `caughtEx.GetType().Name` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @RubenBartelink Yes, Indeed the reasoning is to have the exception show up in a log file instead of the somewhat obtrusive stack trace. As with anything, it depends on what you need. I generally code exception handling like that during development so I can easily track errors, and then clean them up or adjust them as needed (invoking the stack traces when needed).
As I said, I mostly resort to this when working with codebases where proper exception handling was neglected by previous developers.

Comment: Hm, each to their own - for me the stacktrace back to where it was thrown is not something I'd be willing to give up as your example does. I'd either want to log it or pass it on as the `InnerException` of my new wrapping one as I said.

Comment: I don't see this as meant for production code, but I just used it to figure out what the exception really was and then replaced it with the sensible version.

Answer (score 48):

**Alternative Solution**

Instead of halting a debug session, just to add some throw-away statements into the code to then recompile/restart.... *why not just use the debugger to answer that question* **immediately** when a breakpoint is hit?

How?

Through the use of the Visual Studio's debug `Immediate Window` one can type in the call to `GetType()` after the breakpoint is hit. Then once <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, the type is provided on the next line.

*The immediate window also allows one to interrogate other variables and classes/structures as needed in that scope.*

See VS Docs: [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2017)

---

For example I needed to divine what exception I was getting and then just extracted the `Name` property of `GetType` to give me that info. All without having to recompile.

[image]

---

###### Special Variable $exception

There is also the special variable `$exception` which can be used in the Immediate window. Typing that in will evaluate the currently caught exception and write out the reflected information of that exception.

Comment: this is the proper answer

Answer (score 17):

```
try
{
    // Some code
}
catch (Web2PDFException ex)
{
    // It's your special exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Any other exception here
}
```

Comment: If there are 10 known exceptions, the catch chain will look ugly.

Answer (score 11):

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    if (err is Web2PDFException)
        DoWhatever();
}
```

but there is probably a better way of doing whatever it is you want.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is equivalent to several other examples.

Answer (score 3):

You should always catch exceptions as concrete as possible, so you should use

```
try
{
    //code
}
catch (Web2PDFException ex)
{
    //Handle the exception here
}
```

You chould of course use something like this if you insist:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    if (err is Web2PDFException)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add some extra information to your exception in your class and then when you catch the exception you can control your custom information to identify your exception

```
this.Data["mykey"]="keyvalue"; //you can add any type of data if you want
```

and then you can get your value

```
string mystr = (string) err.Data["mykey"];
```

like that for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted either. This offers a nice way of providing additional data to your code.

Comment: @jp2code I'm guessing because it doesn't answer the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```c#
var exception = err as Web2PDFException; 

if ( excecption != null ) 
{ 
     Web2PDFException wex = exception; 
     .... 
}
```